Subsets of semigroups or groups with the property $BA=A$
Let $S$ be a semigroup or group, $B\subseteq S$, and denote by $\langle B\rangle$ the sub-semigroup of $S$ generated by $B$. For every $A\subseteq S$:
$$
BA=A\Rightarrow \langle B\rangle A=A
$$
Because $BA=A$ implies $B^n A=A$ (note that $B^2=BB, B^3=B^2 B$, ...), for all $n\in \mathbb{Z}_+$, and so
$$
\langle B\rangle A=(\cup_{n\geq 1} B^n)A=\cup_{n\geq 1}B^nA=A.
$$
Is the converse true (does $\langle B\rangle A=A$ imply $BA=A$)?
Thanks in advance

No, $BA={ba :  b\in B , a\in A}$.

$\langle B\rangle A = A$ implies that $BA \subseteq A$, so $B^k A$'s ($k \ge 0$) form a descending chain under inclusion (multiplying by $B$), and $\bigcup \limits_{i=1}^\infty B^k A = BA$.

Good. Hence, $A=\langle B\rangle A=BA$ and so $A=BA$, right? (Thanks)

Theorem: Let $S$ be a semigroup or group, $B \subseteq S$, and denote by $\langle B\rangle$ the sub-semigroup of $S$ generated by $B$. For every $A \subseteq S$ :
$$
\langle B\rangle A=A \Longrightarrow B A=A
$$
$\textbf{Proof:}$ Suppose $\langle B\rangle A=A$. Recall that $\langle B\rangle$ consists of all finite products of elements from $B$. Therefore, $\langle B\rangle$ includes all sets of the form $B^n$ for $n \geq 1$, where $B^n$ is defined inductively by $B^1=B$ and $B^{n+1}=B^n B$.
Given that $\langle B\rangle A=A$, we know that for any $x \in A$ and any element $b \in\langle B\rangle$, the product $b x$ is still within $A$. This is true for all elements of $\langle B\rangle$, including all elements of each $B^n$.
To prove $B A=A$, consider any $b \in B$ and $a \in A$. Since $b \in B \subseteq\langle B\rangle$, and we have $\langle B\rangle A=$ $A$, it follows directly that $b a \in A$. Thus, we have shown that every element of $B A$ is in $A$, which implies $B A \subseteq A$.
Since $A \subseteq B A$ is immediate by the identity property (every $a \in A$ can be written as $e a$ for $e$ the identity element in $S$, and $e \in\langle B\rangle$ ), we conclude that $B A=A$.
Therefore, the inclusion $\langle B\rangle A=A$ implies $B A=A$. This completes the proof.

Semigroups don't need to have identities. Those are monoids. So there need not be an $e$ in $S$, let alone in $\langle B\rangle$.

@Snowball, @ Arturo Magidin. Thanks. The above comments (under the question) answer it (right?)
